# Using Python Requests to scrape linkedin.com profile page not working

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a profile page from linkedin.com (just for testing HTTP requests, no plans to build a full-on scraper). However, the response HTML does not display the same HTML which is shown in the browser, and i am getting a status code of `999`

```
{
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
   "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
   "Host": "www.linkedin.com",
   "Referer": "https://www.linkedin.com"
        }

r = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/reidhoffman/', headers=headers)
print(r.status_code) # 999
print(r.text) # different HTML from browser
```

Are there any additional headers required?